# Algorithm for Counting Sorted Strings (Homebrew "uniq -c")

Tags: c++, algorithm, unix, string, counting

I have the following sorted data:

```
AAA
AAA
TCG
TTT
TTT
TTT
```

I want to count the occurrences of each String:

```
AAA 2
TCG 1
TTT 3
```

I know I can do that using `uniq -c`, but here I need to do extra processing on the overall C++ code that I have.

I am stuck with this construct (modified according to 'pgras' suggestion):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
    if (arg_count !=2 ) {
        cerr << "expected one argument" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    string line;
    ifstream myfile (arg_vec[1]);


    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int count;
        string lastTag = "";

        while (getline(myfile,line) )
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            string Tag;

            ss >> Tag; // read first column
            //cout << Tag << endl; 

            if (Tag != lastTag) {
               lastTag = Tag;
               count = 0;
            }
            else {
                count++;
            }

             cout << lastTag << " " << count << endl;
        }
        cout << lastTag << " " << count << endl;
        myfile.close();

    }
    else {cout << "Unable to open file";}
    return 0;
}
```

It prints this wrong result:

```
AAA 0
AAA 1
TCT 0
TTT 0
TTT 1
TTT 2
TTT 2
```

Comment: This won't compile. Count isn't defined, for example. I'm not clear on what your "extra processing" is, either. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @John: I will need to process that uniq tag by giving some value, and prints those tags again along with the count, e.g.  AAA 2 -40 40 40

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear. What are the "-40 40 40" in your last example here?

Comment: @John: it's the extra stuff given by a function that takes the tag as param

Comment: Replace count = 0 to count = 1
Remove the "cout << lastTag << " " << count << endl;" from the while loop
Inside the if (Tag != lastTag) before the lastTag = Tag; place
if(lastTag != "") cout << lastTag << " " << count << endl;
And you will have the ouput you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to reset counter when tag is different from lastTag, and increment if it's the same... When the tag is different you can handle the previous tag with it's associated count value (before you reset count)...

Comment: @pgras: I modified, but maybe I still dont' get you.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to print it out, your algorithm is ok. If you want to pass it to another function, you can use for example STL map.

```
map<string, int> dict;

while(getline(myfile,line)) {
          string Tag;
          stringstream ss(line);
          ss >> Tag;
          if (dict.count(Tag) == 0) 
               dict[Tag] = 1;
           else
               dict[Tag]++;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the extra `if` inside the loop. The [] operator creates a default-constructed item if none exists.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>


std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& out, const std::pair< std::string, size_t >& rhs )
{
    out << rhs.first << ", " << rhs.second;
    return out;
}

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream inp( "mysorted_data.txt" );
    std::string str;
    std::map < std::string, size_t > words_count;
    while ( inp >> str )
    {
        words_count[str]++;
    }

    std::copy( 
        words_count.begin(), 
        words_count.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator< std::pair< std::string, size_t > >( std::cout, "\n" ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your data indeed consists of DNA strings of length 3 (or more general length *N* where *N* is quite small), you can make this very efficient by using a q-gram table which is a specialized hash table with a table size of 4<sup>*N*</sup> and the following hashing function:

```
// Disregard error codes.
int char2dna_lookup[] = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 0x0  – 0xF
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 0x10 – 0x1F
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 0x20 – 0x2F
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 0x30 – 0x3F
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // A    – P
    0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Q    – 0x5F
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 0x60 – 0x6F
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // 0x70 – 0x7F
}

unsigned int hash(string const& dna) {
    unsigned int ret = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dna.length(); ++i)
        ret = ret * 4 + char2dna_lookup[dna[i]];

    return ret;
}
```

You can now index your array very efficiently.

```
ifstream ifs("data.txt");
string line;

if (not ifs >> line)
    exit(1);

unsigned* frequencies = new unsigned int[line.length()];

frequencies[hash(line)] = 1;

while (ifs >> line)
    ++frequencies[hash(line)];

// Print the frequencies …

delete[] frequencies;
```

Alternatively, use a library such as [SeqAn](http://www.seqan.de) for such tasks.

Comment: Notice, the code is untested. There might be errors in the lookup table (or elsewhere).

Answer (score 2):

I think that all you have to do is replace this

```
        if (Tag != lastTag) {
           lastTag = Tag;
           count = 0;
        }
        else {
            count++;
        }

        cout << lastTag << " " << count << endl;
```

with this:

```
        if (Tag != lastTag) {
            if (lastTag != "") {  // don't print initial empty tag
                cout << lastTag << " " << count << endl;
            }
            lastTag = Tag;
            count = 1; // count current
          } else {
            count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks slightly broken syntactically (the `ifstream`, ...), but the overall algorithm I think is sound. Read lines, and increment a counter every time the line is the same as the one before. There might be some boundary conditions to consider (what if the input is only one line?), but you'll catch those during testing.

Comment: And remember to start with -1 for the initial item, or else the question is slightly erroneous. ;)

That said, the other answers until now are not as efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the stringstream just to get the tag seems a bit of overkill - I'd probably use string::substr. That aside, what do you think is wrong with your code? What do you want to improve?

**Edit:** Next thing, we will be getting downvoted for breathing...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

class Counter
{   private: std::map<std::string,int>&   m_count;
    public:  Counter(std::map<std::string,int>& data) :m_count(data){}
        void operator()(std::string const& word)
        {
            m_count[word]++;
        }};
class Printer
{   private: std::ostream& m_out;
    public:  Printer(std::ostream& out) :m_out(out) {}
        void operator()(std::map<std::string,int>::value_type const& data)
        {
            m_out << data.first << " = " << data.second << "\n";
        }};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,int>       count;

    for_each(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             Counter(count)
            );

    for_each(count.begin(),count.end(),
             Printer(std::cout)
            );
}
```